# Best Practices for Where clauses

Tags: haskell, design-patterns, functional-programming, where-clause

I wrote a simple tic-tac-toe program in Haskell.  It runs on the command line, has a one and two player mode, and implements a minimax algorithm when you play against it.

I'm used to writing proper code in OO languages, but Haskell is new to me.  This code works reasonably well, but seems hard to read (even to me!).  Any suggestions on how to make this code more...Haskellian?

```
import Data.List
import Data.Char
import Data.Maybe
import Control.Monad

data Square = A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | X | O deriving (Read, Eq, Ord)
instance Show Square where
   show A = "a" 
   show B = "b" 
   show C = "c" 
   show D = "d" 
   show E = "e" 
   show F = "f" 
   show G = "g" 
   show H = "h" 
   show I = "i" 
   show X = "X" 
   show O = "O"
type Row = [Square]
type Board = [Row]
data Player = PX | PO deriving (Read, Eq)
instance Show Player where
   show PX = "Player X"
   show PO = "Player O"
data Result = XWin | Tie | OWin deriving (Read, Show, Eq, Ord) 

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn "Let's play some tic tac toe!!!"
    putStrLn "Yeeeaaaaaahh!!!"
    gameSelect

gameSelect :: IO ()
gameSelect = do
    putStrLn "Who gonna play, one playa or two??? (Enter 1 or 2)"
    gameMode <- getLine
    case gameMode of "1" -> onePlayerMode
                     "2" -> twoPlayerMode
                     gameMode -> gameSelect
    where onePlayerMode = do
             putStrLn "One playa"
             putStrLn "Cool!  Get ready to play...AGAINST MY INVINCIBLE TIC TAC TOE AI!!!!! HAHAHAHA!!!"
             gameLoop 1 emptyBoard PX
          twoPlayerMode = do
             putStrLn "Two players"
             gameLoop 2 emptyBoard PX
          emptyBoard = [[A,B,C],[D,E,F],[G,H,I]]

gameLoop :: Int -> Board -> Player -> IO ()
gameLoop noOfPlayers board player = do
    case detectWin board of Just XWin -> endgame board XWin
                            Just OWin -> endgame board OWin
                            Just Tie -> endgame board Tie
                            Nothing -> if noOfPlayers == 1
                                       then if player == PX 
                                            then enterMove 1 board player 
                                            else enterBestMove board PO
                                       else enterMove 2 board player

enterMove :: Int -> Board -> Player -> IO () 
enterMove noOfPlayers board player = do
     displayBoard board
     if noOfPlayers == 1
     then do putStrLn ("Make your move. (A-I)")
     else do putStrLn (show player ++ ", it's your turn. (A-I)")
     move <- getLine
     print move
     if not $ move `elem` ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"]
         then do
            putStrLn $ move ++ " is not a move, doofus"
            gameLoop noOfPlayers board player
         else if (read (map toUpper move) :: Square) `elem` [ sq | sq <- concat board]
            then do
               gameLoop noOfPlayers (newBoard (read (map toUpper move) :: Square) player board) (if player == PX then PO else PX)
            else do
               putStrLn "That square is already occupied"
               gameLoop noOfPlayers board player

enterBestMove :: Board -> Player -> IO ()
enterBestMove board player = gameLoop 1 (newBoard bestmove player board) PX
    where bestmove = fst $ findBestMove PO board
          findBestMove :: Player -> Board -> (Square, Result)
          findBestMove player board
            | player == PO = findMax results
            | player == PX = findMin results
            where findMin = foldl1 (\ acc x -> if snd x < snd acc then x else acc)
                  findMax = foldl1 (\ acc x -> if snd x > snd acc then x else acc)
                  results = [ (sq, getResult b) | (sq, b) <- boards player board ]
                  getResult b = if detectWin b == Nothing 
                                then snd (findBestMove (if player == PX then PO else PX) b) 
                                else fromJust $ detectWin b
                  boards :: Player -> Board -> [(Square, Board)]
                  boards player board = [(sq, newBoard sq player board) | sq <- concat board, sq /= X, sq /=O]

displayBoard :: Board -> IO ()
displayBoard board = do
    mapM_ print board

newBoard :: Square -> Player -> Board -> Board
newBoard move player board = [ [if sq == move then mark else sq | sq <- row] | row <- board]
    where mark = if player == PX then X else O

detectWin :: Board -> (Maybe Result)
detectWin board
   | [X,X,X] `elem` board ++ transpose board = Just XWin
   | [X,X,X] `elem` [diagonal1 board, diagonal2 board] = Just XWin
   | [O,O,O] `elem` board ++ transpose board = Just OWin
   | [O,O,O] `elem` [diagonal1 board, diagonal2 board] = Just OWin
   | [X,X,X,X,X,O,O,O,O] == (sort $ concat board) = Just Tie
   | otherwise = Nothing
   where
     diagonal1 :: Board -> [Square]
     diagonal1 bs = bs!!0!!0 : bs!!1!!1 : bs!!2!!2 : []
     diagonal2 :: Board -> [Square]
     diagonal2 bs = bs!!0!!2 : bs!!1!!1 : bs!!2!!0 : []

endgame :: Board -> Result -> IO ()
endgame board result = do
    displayBoard board
    if result `elem` [XWin, OWin]
        then 
            let player = if result == XWin then PX else PO
            in do 
                putStrLn ("The game is over, and " ++ show player ++ " wins!")
                putStrLn ((if player == PX then show PO else show PX) ++ " is a loser lol")
        else do
            putStrLn "The game is a tie"
            putStrLn "You are both losers!  Ugh!"
    putStrLn "Want to play again? (y/n)"
    again <- getLine
    if again `elem` ["y", "Y", "yes", "Yes", "YES"] 
        then gameSelect 
        else do
            putStrLn "Goodbye"
```

---

EDIT: with special thanks to @Chi and @Caridorc, I've made the following changes.  Further suggestions will be considered and updated as well

```
import Data.List
import Data.Char
import Data.Maybe
import Control.Monad

data Square = A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | X | O deriving (Read, Eq, Ord)
instance Show Square where
   show A = "a" 
   show B = "b" 
   show C = "c" 
   show D = "d" 
   show E = "e" 
   show F = "f" 
   show G = "g" 
   show H = "h" 
   show I = "i" 
   show X = "X" 
   show O = "O"
type Row = [Square]
type Board = [Row]
data Player = PX | PO deriving (Read, Eq)
instance Show Player where
   show PX = "Player X"
   show PO = "Player O"
data Result = XWin | Tie | OWin deriving (Read, Show, Eq, Ord) 

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn "Let's play some tic tac toe!!!"
    putStrLn "Yeeeaaaaaahh!!!"
    gameSelect

gameSelect :: IO ()
gameSelect = do
    putStrLn "Who gonna play, one playa or two??? (Enter 1 or 2)"
    gameMode <- getLine
    case gameMode of 
      "1" -> onePlayerMode
      "2" -> twoPlayerMode
      _ -> gameSelect
    where onePlayerMode = do
             putStrLn "One playa"
             putStrLn "Cool!  Get ready to play...AGAINST MY INVINCIBLE TIC TAC TOE AI!!!!! HAHAHAHA!!!"
             gameLoop 1 emptyBoard PX
          twoPlayerMode = do
             putStrLn "Two players"
             gameLoop 2 emptyBoard PX
          emptyBoard = [[A,B,C],[D,E,F],[G,H,I]]

displayBoard :: Board -> IO ()
displayBoard board = do
    mapM_ print board

otherPlayer :: Player -> Player
otherPlayer PX = PO
otherPlayer PO = PX

gameLoop :: Int -> Board -> Player -> IO ()
gameLoop noOfPlayers board player = do
    case detectWin board of 
      Just res -> endgame board res
      Nothing -> case noOfPlayers of
                   1 -> case player of
                          PX -> enterMove 1 board player
                          PO -> enterBestMove board PO 
                   2 -> enterMove 2 board player

enterMove :: Int -> Board -> Player -> IO () 
enterMove noOfPlayers board player = do
     displayBoard board
     case noOfPlayers of
       1 -> do putStrLn ("Make your move. (A-I)")
       2 -> do putStrLn (show player ++ ", it's your turn. (A-I)")
     move <- getLine
     print move
     if not $ move `elem` ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"] then do
        putStrLn $ move ++ " is not a move, doofus"
        gameLoop noOfPlayers board player
     else if (read (map toUpper move) :: Square) `elem` (concat board) then do
            gameLoop noOfPlayers (newBoard (read (map toUpper move) :: Square) player board) (otherPlayer player)
          else do
            putStrLn "That square is already occupied"
            gameLoop noOfPlayers board player

enterBestMove :: Board -> Player -> IO ()
enterBestMove board player = gameLoop 1 (newBoard bestmove player board) PX
    where bestmove = fst $ findBestMove PO board

findBestMove :: Player -> Board -> (Square, Result)  -- minimax algorithm
findBestMove player board
  | player == PO = findMax results
  | player == PX = findMin results
  where findMin = foldl1 (\ acc x -> if snd x < snd acc then x else acc)     
        findMax = foldl1 (\ acc x -> if snd x > snd acc then x else acc)
        results = [ (sq, getResult b) | (sq, b) <- boards player board ]
        getResult b = case detectWin b of
                        Nothing -> snd (findBestMove (otherPlayer player) b)
                        Just x -> x
        boards :: Player -> Board -> [(Square, Board)]
        boards player board = [(sq, newBoard sq player board) | sq <- concat board, sq /= X, sq /=O]

newBoard :: Square -> Player -> Board -> Board
newBoard move player board = [ [if sq == move then mark else sq | sq <- row] | row <- board]
    where mark = if player == PX then X else O

detectWin :: Board -> (Maybe Result)
detectWin board
   | [X,X,X] `elem` (triplets board) = Just XWin
   | [O,O,O] `elem` (triplets board) = Just OWin
   | [X,X,X,X,X,O,O,O,O] == (sort $ concat board) = Just Tie
   | otherwise = Nothing

triplets :: Board -> [[Square]]
triplets board = board ++ transpose board ++ [diagonal1] ++ [diagonal2]
   where
     flat = concat board
     diagonal1 = [flat !! 0, flat !! 4, flat !! 8]
     diagonal2 = [flat !! 2, flat !! 4, flat !! 6]

endgame :: Board -> Result -> IO ()
endgame board result = do
    displayBoard board

    putStrLn $ endGameMessage result

    putStrLn "Want to play again? (y/n)"
    again <- getLine
    if again `elem` ["y", "Y", "yes", "Yes", "YES"] 
    then gameSelect 
    else do
        putStrLn "Goodbye"

endGameMessage :: Result -> String
endGameMessage result
   | result `elem` [XWin, OWin] = winnerNotice ++ loserNotice
   | otherwise = "The game is a tie\n" ++ "You are both losers!  Ugh!"
   where
     winner = case result of
      XWin -> PX
      OWin -> PO
     winnerNotice = "The game is over, and " ++ show winner ++ " wins!\n"
     loserNotice = (show $ otherPlayer winner) ++ " is a loser lol"
```

Comment: Your question is more appropriate for [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I wouldn't say your code looks particularly hard to read... I think _I'd_ find it harder to read if you wrote this in any OO language!  Most of the reason _you_ find it hard to read is certainly that you're not so firm with Haskell yet. As chi pointed out, you also did write some things in less than optimal ways, but they don't affect readability that much. — _However_ it should also be emphasized that your program is very untypical for Haskell code: very little interesting logic in a whole lot of imperative interaction code. “Real” Haskell projects generally have it the other way around.

Comment: Small passing suggestion:  I would probably factorize `data Square = Empty Label | Full Player` instead of the large mixed enumeration you have.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Code style is often a matter of personal preference, in Haskell arguably more than in other languages with a "standard" style guide. Still, here's a few random suggestions.

---

Don't over-indent `case`s: just use another line

```
case gameMode of "1" -> onePlayerMode
                 "2" -> twoPlayerMode
                 gameMode -> gameSelect
```

vs

```
case gameMode of
   "1" -> onePlayerMode
   "2" -> twoPlayerMode
   gameMode -> gameSelect
```

or even

```
case gameMode of
   "1" -> onePlayerMode
   "2" -> twoPlayerMode
   _   -> gameSelect
```

---

`case` is usually preferred to `if .. == Constructor`:

```
if player == PX 
then enterMove 1 board player 
else enterBestMove board PO
```

vs

```
case player of
   PX -> enterMove 1 board player 
   PY -> enterBestMove board PO
```

---

I'd strongly recommend against using partial functions like `fromJust`, since they can crash your program if you forget to check for `Nothing` beforehand. Safer alternatives exist, which never cause such crashes -- less burden on the programmer.

```
if detectWin b == Nothing 
then snd (findBestMove (if player == PX then PO else PX) b) 
else fromJust $ detectWin b
```

vs

```
case detectWin b of
   Nothing -> snd $ findBestMove (if player == PX then PO else PX) b
   Just x  -> x
```

or

```
fromMaybe (snd $ findBestMove (if player == PX then PO else PX) b)
  $ detectWin b
```

---

Try to factorize commonly used functions. For instance

```
nextPlayer PX = PO
nextPlayer PO = PX
```

can replace uses of

```
if player == PX then PO else PX
```

---

No `do` is needed when there's only one statement:

```
if noOfPlayers == 1
then do putStrLn ("Make your move. (A-I)")    -- no need for parentheses here
else do putStrLn (show player ++ ", it's your turn. (A-I)")
```

---

Since you mention `where` in the title, let me state that I have mixed feelings about `where`, in general. I know I often tend to avoid `where` in favor of `let`, but this feeling is not shared with many other Haskellers, so take this with some care.

Personally, I tend to limit my `where` uses to one-liners:

```
foo = f x y
   where x = ...
         y = ...
```

Especially in `do` blocks, which might span several lines, I prefer `let`s:

```
foo = do
   line
   line using x     -- what is x ??!?
   line
   ...
   line
  where x = ...     -- ah, here it is
```

vs

```
foo = do
   line
   let x = ...
   line using x
   line
   ...
   line
```

However, feel free to adopt the style you find more readable.

---

Also don't forget to add a few comments, as @mawalker points out. Some definitions are obvious and don't need any explanation. Others could benefit from a few lines explaining the purpose.

Comment: I don't know Haskell, but you make it look almost readable... (Actually not joking, your suggestions are very good and help readability quite nicely from someone who doesn't know Haskell right now) But... What about comments? His program has 0 lines of comments and I'm curious as to what your suggestions would be concerning that in Haskell.